# SSH still asking for password despite conf and permissions set up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keygen

I have a remote server (Contabo), and a Host (my Dell computer).
I have created a new sudo user laura instead of using root all the time, with:

```
adduser laura
usermod -aG sudo laura
```

I have generated SSH keys on my Dell computer with the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

The ssh-copy-id did not work, however I've used this command to send the public key newly generated, into my Contabo Server:

sudo scp id_rsa_contabo.pub laura@:/home/laura/.ssh/

Of course I have replaced  with the IP of my Contabo server. I can see the public key inside my .ssh folder, which I insert into an **authorized_keys** file.

However, no matter what I do (and I've been trying for hours now), when I do this:

```
ssh laura@<IP>
```

With < IP > replaced by the IP address of my Contabo server, the system still asks me for a password!

What I've tried so far:

- I made sure permissions were correct, as I read several articles on StackOF saying the .ssh folder should be set at 700 and the authorized_keys file should be at 600.
- The naming is correct: authorized_keys with Z instead of S. Also, when I've generated a pair of key, I've named it id_rsa_contabo, and I did the following:

  ssh-agent bash

  ssh-add ~/.ssh/contabo_rsa

This is because my file does not match the default naming convention for keys (normally it’s id_rsa).

- Trying to see what's going on in the var/log/auth : I can see bots trying to brute-force my server and failing, and I can also see myself connecting to the Contabo server with a password : nothing strange in this file to me.
- Trying the following command:

  ssh laura@161.97.167.13 -v

No error message, however my file id_rsa_contabo (the one in the authorized_keys) is not even read by the system. See my screenshot for the output of this command:

[image: screenshotssh]

- Trying the following command to force the system to use my newly generated key :

  ssh -i id_rsa_contabo.pub laura@161.97.167.13
- I have checked the content of /**etc/ss/ssh_config** and **/etc/ss/sshd_config**. I have the following in both:

  RSAAuthentication yes
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

.

Nothing seems to work. Please can a good samaritan help me? :(

Comment: authorized_keys on the destination system should contain the contents of the rsa.pub file on the source system. It looks like you copied authorized_keys from the source to the destination, which is likely not what you want.

Comment: I think I've already done this step :) This is what I have:
The authorized_keys file on the Contabo Server contains the public key, which is found in the Host Dell Computer at: /home/laura/.ssh/id_rsa_contabo.pub

Is this what you where trying to suggest?

Comment: I have edited my question, as it was confusing tho.

Comment: Can you verify that ~laura/.ssh is mode 700 and ~laura/.ssh/authorized_keys is mode 600 on the server and then try (note the full path on the identify file): `ssh -vv -i ~laura/.ssh/id_rsa_contabo.pub laura@161.97.167.13`

Comment: Hi Wayne, today when I arrived at the office, the command ssh laura@IP was working as intended : without asking a password. And I've done nothing more than my steps described above, and restarted the computer. So it's working (but I have no idea why). Thanks for your messages tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now (after I came in the office the next day). I believe I forgot to restart the services with the following command...

```
systemctls restart ...
```